# Как "подавить" сообщение при выполнении команды xcopy

Tags: cmd

Пытаюсь скопировать файл с помощью команды:

```
xcopy /Y /I c:\file.txt c:\tmp\file.txt
```

В результате получаю сообщение:

> Does c:\tmp\file.txt specify a file name or directory name on the
>   target (F = file, D = directory)?

Каким образом можна "подавить" данное сообщение? [Ключи](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) `/F /I` не помогают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно:

- воспользоваться командой `echo f | xcopy /f /y srcFile destFile...`
- вместо `xcopy` воспользоваться командой `copy`. Но при таком подходе не будет создана структура папок